# Alpha animation drawn over ActionBar leaves a trail

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation

**Context:** I have an activity `ItemDetailActivity` and 2 fragments, `ItemDetailFrontFragment` and `ItemDetailBackFragment`. The 2 fragments are being hosted in the `ItemDetailActivity` and act like a front and a back of a card (think regular card deck), and I switch between them in order for the user to see additional info on the back of the card. I also have animations attached to the fragment transactions: front in, back in, front out, back out; and use them as such:

```
 getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(
                    R.animator.card_flip_back_in, R.animator.card_flip_front_out,
                    R.animator.card_flip_front_in, R.animator.card_flip_back_out)
```

As an example of animation, here's `card_flip_front_out`:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full"/>

<objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_half"/>

<objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.8"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_quarter"/>

<objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.6"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_quarter"/>
```

**Problem:** Every single part of the implementation described above works perfectly and as planned, except from a visual glitch. When the top part of the card rotates above the `ActionBar`, a trail of the layout from that fragment remains drawn on top of the `ActionBar`. For example, if in that fragment I have a red `ImageView` and a part of that rotates on top of the `ActionBar`, then a red trail remains present on it.

I encountered this issue as soon as I added the `alpha` animation. If I remove it from the set, then this problem disappears. Unfortunately, I need that `alpha` animation, so I can't remove it.

I tried setting the `ActionBar` as an overlay, then adding padding to the layout in order to push it down to its correct place, but this didn't change anything. The animation was still drawn on top of the `ActionBar`.

Comment: This is really weird... apparently this is not an issue on the Nexus 5. It is, however, on the Nexus 7 2012. Both running 4.4.2

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: No, I just made the animation so that the edges don't overlap anymore.

Comment: I'm seeing this on 4.4.2 device as well. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this problem still resides, I would recommend changing the animation slightly as to not overlap the ActionBar. For example, do a resize of the content which you want to animate for it to move beneath the ActionBar. That's what I did in the end and it not only solved the problem, it looked even more crisp.

I would also recommend trying it out with the new Support Lib v21 and maybe the Toolbar API and check if they managed to fix this issue with these 2 updates. Might work, might not work. Worth a shot anyway.